# How many possible six-word sentences

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A word is defined as a nonempty (possibly meaningless) sequence of letters. How many $6$-word sentences can be made using each of the $26$ letters of the alphabet exactly once? Generalise the result to the number of sentences consisting of $w$ nonempty words using exactly once each letter from a $l$-letter alphabet.

**My Attempt** We have $^{26}P_{26}$ ways of arranging the $26$ letters. Then, in order to have six words there have to be five spaces. For each of the previous arrangements there are $^{25}C_{5}$ ways to separate groups of letters into six. Thus, the answer is $^{26}P_{26}\,\cdot\,^{25}C_{5}\approx2\times10^{31}$.

For the generalisation we have $^{l}P_{l}\,\cdot\,^{l-1}C_{w-1}$.

Comment: This is correct.  It is a nice application of the stars and bars technique.

Comment: @TravisJ Ah, that didn't occur to me. But only for the $^{25}C_{5}$ part?

Comment: Yes, the method of breaking up the 26 letter word into smaller words.  I should point out that this is correct provided that you allow words to have no letters.

Comment: The second part should be 5 out of 25, otherwise you will be getting combinations with less than 6 words

Comment: @DannyDan What are you referring to exactly please? Thanks.

Comment: @bibo_extreme I am not sure I understand the notation so I may have had to hold back my comment. I understood that you were putting the 5 spaces each in any of the 25 possible locations, and if you do that then you may have two spaces in the same location which reduces the number of words, which does not meet the question requirements.